# c# ASP.NET MVC 4 "An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time" without any async task happening

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application that in a controller Im getting the following error:

[image]

The thing is that nothing async is happening inside but I just found what code is causing this and is breaking my head:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Roles> roles = new List<Roles>();
            roles = _service.GetRolesByCompany(); // this is syncronous task returning a List<Roles>

            if (roles != null && roles.Count > 0)
            {
                message = "All good";
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Missing Settings";
            }

            return View(message);
        }
```

If by some reason I remove the condition: `roles.Count > 0`  then the error is gone and everything works fine.

`roles` property is already resolved, is not something pending to resolve. Here is the code of the method `GetRolesByCompany` :

```
public List<Roles> GetRolesByCompany() {

            List<Roles> roles= null;
 
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                try
                {
                    roles = conn.Query<Roles>("GetRolesByCompany",
                                 null,
                                 commandTimeout: 0,
                                 commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                   
                }

            }

            return roles;
        }
```

If you see the method executes a `.ToList()` and this resolves the list. So there is nothing async that could explain the error.

> This is breaking my head since this morning, any clue why is this happening?

Comment: What is `conn.Query<T>` here?

Comment: It’s a Dapper extension.

Comment: What if you replace the GetRolesNyCompany with a dummy method that returns an empty list but you keep the Count?

Comment: Good point let me do that.

Comment: Woow same thing!! this is crazy. I just commented the line where it calls the service and the error stills when the count happens. Could be something with my computer that is not ok?

Comment: And if you completely comment out this line calling this method? You set the `roles` to new empty list anyway.

Comment: Same issue happens, I commented the line calling the method and I just leaved the empty list.

Comment: Something is very wrong here. Could be your view that tires to get the data on its own.